# Command line or other tools to collect outlook add-in's installed?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there any tool or utility to see the list of admin-managed Outlook add-ins installed on a user machine?

This will be helpful to gather diagnostics using script rather than asking users to take screenshots and upload manually?

Can we get manifest info used by the add-in using any utility tool or from UI?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tools. You can find the list of web add-ins in the hidden items of your Inbox folder. If you try to use [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) and navigate to the associated content table of your Inbox where you can find the list of hidden messages:

[image]

Every message with a message class set to the `IPM.Configuration.ClientExtension.*` represents a web add-in installed for your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Admins can run this powershell commandlet to get add-ins for individual users:

```
Get-App -Mailbox <userEmailAddress>
```